# How to draw on a UIView with core graphics?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I can't figure out why I can't draw on the UIView layer. Is that possible?

**My example code i am using:**

```
@implementation Menu
UIView *window;
UIWindow *mainWindow;
```

```
CGSize viewwidth;
    viewwidth=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
// viewwidth.width or viewwidth.height
//My UIView
window = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, viewwidth.width, viewwidth.height)];
    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    window.layer.opacity = 1.0f;
    [window setNeedsDisplay];
    [mainWindow addSubview: window];
```

**My method drawRect for drawing:**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);   //this is the transparent color
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rectangle);    //this will draw the border
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, the problem is i get a empty white screen?

Comment: Is `mainWindow` something valid when you call `addSubview`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a project and chose to use Storyboards you will set a ViewController to your `Main.storyboard` in Interface Builder.

[image]

There are differences between iOS Apps that use `SceneDelegates` and those who do not (iOS before 13.0). But your chosen ViewController will be assigned to be used from within your Main Window/Scene when the App will be loaded. In AppDelegate.m (before iOS 13) or SceneDelegate.m (starting iOS 13) you could directly access or even assign this yourself to the `self.window.rootViewController` property.

Do to inheritance of `UIViewController` which come with a basic `UIView` ready to work with under `self.view` (in this example inside ViewController.m) you can place more Subviews to that property with `[self.view addSubview:yourOtherView]`.

`-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` is a method that belongs to `UIView` and will be called when the view is set to update or layout. But it is important to know that this is not the only method where you can place drawing code. `UIView:drawRect` can be avoided to lower the Energy impact and workload you app is consuming when you don't need repeatedly redrawing the graphics. Also the workload is heavy influenced to be lower when you are able to lower the CGRect size to draw inside.

One word to value naming.. you will have less confusing code when values are named after the content they belong to. So naming a property "window" which is actually a UIView will stress you when your project becomes more complex. So you created a local value with name `mainWindow` while `window` is already existing. When doing so you will have to assign your mainWindow to the apps UIWindow yourself to make it available. And the UIView you named `window` can confuse you while `_window` or `self.window` is already existing as part of the AppDelegate or SceneDelegate. And as mentioned above you have a UIView that belongs to the UIViewController you assigned in Storyboard or in code.

Your drawing code is valid. It may be invisible to you because of transparency you choose to go for.

below some code to compare to for your ViewController.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyGraphicView.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) MyGraphicView *graphicView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    _graphicView = [[MyGraphicView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:_graphicView];
}
@end
```

and a MyGraphicView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyGraphicView : UIView

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

and corresponding MyGraphicView.h

```
#import "MyGraphicView.h"

@implementation MyGraphicView

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
// This method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rectangle);
}

@end
```

Comment: made the CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor green so you would see if it draws correctly